# what was the older version of itext gradle dependency which supported the htmlWorker class(it is deprecated in newer version )

Tags: android, itext

I have a simple html text which i want to convert into pdf.I want to use HtmlWorker class but is deprecated in newer version so i want to use older version of itext library.

Comment: what do you mean by "newer version" and "older version" ?

Comment: You should not go back to a version that is more than 10 years old. You will not find any technical support for that old version. Do not use the `HTMLWorker` class, there is a very good reason why it is deprecated: it is incomplete and contains bugs that will never be fixed. Instead use the recent version: iText 7.1.5, with the pdfHTML add-on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow official `Itext library` and it contains all the released version of library [Click here](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/releases)